# evaluation monitor in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

What I am trying to achieve is similar to a logging facility but for monitoring and streaming arbitrary data from a running simulation. Here is the simplified situation:

```
module Sim (V:VEC) = struct
  module V = V
  module M = struct type data = V.t end
  let loop n init_data = 
    let running_data = ref init_data in
    for _i = 1 to n do 
      (*?*) (* monitor here: data => outside world *)
      rdata := process_data !rdata
    done
end
```

While simulation loops, at the `?` I may want to 'tap' data and accumulate it. Other times, I want to just let it run and disable the data stream with minimal overhead -- the `?` is in a tight loop. So I want the streaming to be configurable with little cost.

What I have now is this:

```
module Sim (V:VEC) = struct
  module V = V
  module M = struct type data = V.t end
  let data_monitor : (M.data -> unit) ref = ref (fun d -> ())
  let loop n init_data = 
    let running_data = ref init_data in
    for _i = 1 to n do 
      !data_monitor !rdata; (* monitor here *)
      rdata := process_data !rdata
    done
end
```

Ie. I put a stub monitoring function reference in there. In the actual application script I can then assign a function which e.g. accumulates the data values into a list or some such. It works.

So the question is: is this the best/lowest overhead/nicest way to achieve what I want?

This approach seems a bit hackish, I would rather use the module system instead of function pointers. However, the data type to be streamed is only defined inside the functor `Sim`. So making a monitoring function in another module `Sampler` outside of `Sim` and parametrizing `Sim` by that, seems not convenient and/or requires duplication of code or recursive modules. I tried, but I was not able to make all types equal.

Edit: Here is roughly what it tried without function refs:

```
module Sampler (V:VEC) : sig
  module V : VEC
  type data = V.t
  val monitor_data : data -> unit
end 
with type data = V.t = struct
  module V = V
  type data = V.t
  let monitor_data data = store_away_the data
end

module Sim (V:VEC) (Sampler:??) : sig
  ...
end with type M.data = V.t
```

At the `??` I was not sure how to specify the output signature of Sampler, since the input signature `VEC` is still free; also I was not sure how exactly to make the type equality work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong here.

Comment: When trying to make types equal, did you use `with type` constraints?

Comment: yes, see edit at the end of the question

Comment: In your question it says that the type to be streamed is defined only inside `Sim`. However, that type (`M.data`) is equal to `V.t`. Is that a simplification, or is the question only about making `M.data` be equal to `V.t` in `Sampler`? As it is now, if `Sampler` is defined as is, it cannot handle (except parametrically) any types except those in `V`.

Comment: In the meantime, have you considered simply passing the "sampler" function to `loop`, perhaps as an optional argument? And also converting the loop to something `fold`-like?

Comment: to the previous comment: it's a(n over) simplification. in fact, inside Sim.M, a new record type is constructed with one field equal to V.t . So then, the naive idea of making Sampler only depend on V should be doomed i guess. but recursive modules are scary, or more precisely, i would find it super cumbersome to have to define the full output sig of Sim manually. Sim is very long in the actual code.

Comment: passing the monitor function to loop: maybe this is a way out? so i would instantiate Sim(V) to a concrete module in the application script. then i would define the sampler function using types from Sim(V). then call loop with that function. this could be it?! maybe still not as nice as having a module with all sampling functions neatly packaged together but it seems like it should work..

Comment: I think you just need to pass `M` to `Sampler` if you want to do it the module way. `Sim` becomes a higher-order functor, so I guess your question will then be about how to write the signature of `Sampler` in the declaration of `Sim`? Since I saw your answer for my other query, I say that it's much more straightforward to do this with a higher-order function instead, if that is sufficient for your needs, so I will write an answer that shows how.

Comment: By the way, note that for the functions in `Sampler` to be able to do anything interesting with `M.data`, they have to know what `M.data` actually is, or have access to other functions that do. So, I think it will be very tricky to define `Sampler` over unknown (parametric) `M.data` types. It is much easier to define them over ground (instantiated) `M.data` types as you mentioned in one of your comments above. The simplified code in the question doesn't seem to justify using a higher-order functor, but you may have complex constraints I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you may be able to do something like this using higher-order functions (instead of having to resort to a higher-order functor):

```
module type VEC = sig type t end
module Vec = struct type t = unit end

module Sim (V : VEC) =
struct
  module M = struct type data = V.t list end

  let process x = x

  let rec loop ?(monitor : M.data -> unit = ignore) n data =
    if n <= 0 then data
    else
      (monitor [];
      process data |> loop ~monitor (n - 1))
end

module MySim = Sim (Vec)

let monitor _ = print_endline "foo"

let () =
  MySim.loop ~monitor 5 ()
```

`loop` above takes an optional function as argument, which you can pass with the syntax `~monitor:my_fun` or `~monitor:(fun data -> ...)`. If you already have a value called `monitor` in scope, you can simply do `~monitor` to pass it. If you don't pass anything, the default value is `ignore` (i.e. `fun _ -> ()`).

I also rewrote `loop` in recursive style. The code above prints `foo` 5 times. Note that your `monitor` function can still come from `Sampler` module, you just have no need to pass the whole module in when instantiating `Sim`.

**EDIT**: If you still want to declare a higher-order functor, here is how you do it (...)

**EDIT 2**: Changed the example given additional information that the reason for the higher-order functor is that there are multiple monitoring functions to call. Note that in this case, there are still other solutions besides a higher-order functor: you could group the functions into a record, and pass the record to `loop`. Similar to this, you could pass a first-class module. Or, you could create one function that takes a variant type whose cases indicate at what stage the monitoring function is being called, and carry the data associated with each stage. You can also use classes for this, though I wouldn't recommend it. The functor approach does have an advantage, however, if you are committed to declaring `M` inside `Sim`.

I have omitted the signature `VEC` from the sketch because I'm under the impression that the questioner understands where to add it, and there is no problem with it :)

```
module type SAMPLER =
sig
  type data
  val monitor : data -> unit
  val monitor' : data list -> unit
end

(* These are created inside Sim. *)
module type DATA =
sig
  type data
  val show : data -> string
end

(* Note that I am using destructive substitution (:=) to avoid the need
   to have a type data declared in the body of MySampler below. If you
   use a regular type equality constraint, you need to add a field
   "type data = Data.data" to the body. *)
module type SAMPLER_FN =
  functor (Data : DATA) -> SAMPLER with type data := Data.data

(* This is the higher-order functor (it takes another functor as an
   argument). *)
module Sim (Sampler_fn : SAMPLER_FN) =
struct
  (* Corresponds to module "Sim.M" in the question. *)
  module Data =
  struct
    type data = string
    let show s = s
  end

  (* Note that without additional type constraints or rearrangements,
     the type data is abstract to Sampler (more precisely, Sampler_fn
     is parametric over Data). This means that Sampler_fn can't
     analyze values of type data, which is why we need to provide
     functions such as Data.show to Sampler_fn for instances of
     Sampler_fn to be "useful". If you are trying to avoid this and
     are having trouble with these specific constraints, let me
     know. The ability to pass types and related values (functions
     in this case) to Sampler_fn is the main argument in favor of
     using a higher-order functor. *)
  module Sampler = Sampler_fn (Data)

  let simulate x =
    (* Call one monitoring function. *)
    Sampler.monitor "hi!";
    (* Do some computation and call another monitoring function. *)
    Sampler.monitor' ["hello"; "world"]
end
```

---

Usage:

```
module MySampler (Data : DATA) =
struct
  let monitor data = data |> Data.show |> print_endline
  let monitor' data =
    data
    |> List.map Data.show
    |> String.concat " "
    |> print_endline
end

module MySim = Sim (MySampler)

let () = MySim.simulate ()
```

This prints

```
hi!
hello world
```

Comment: thanks for making self contained examples! i'm not sure i understand the higher-order functor solution. here is what i figured: SAMPLER does not know any types dependent on VEC. but this is not a problem since  monitor could act by side effect, e.g. storing a VEC.t into a global list; SAMPLER_FN allows for that. the VEC.t would need to come from a closure. now Sim is a higher order functor; does that mean V is available in the body of Sim?  if yes how? i guess i do not see how to write test so that monitor actually exports some VEC.t (list) to the outside.

Comment: anyway, the solution passing the monitor function is probably the way to go. the only thing that's missing is that there is not one place where all 'monitoring settings' are nicely bundled together -- in the actual problem there are many different possible monitoring functions. this would then need to be handled in the application script.

Comment: The higher-order functor sketch above just focused on the syntax of declaring a higher-order functor. I'll edit it (in about an hour or two) to be closer to what I think your scenario is, and maybe it will answer some of your questions. That `Sim` is a higher-order functor simply means it has `Sampler_fn`, another functor, as an argument, so it can apply it to its nested module `M` – then, the body of `Sampler_fn` can depend on such modules, including declaring monitoring functions that depend on types in `M`.

Comment: As for bundling in the case of a higher-order function, I am still not sure what prevents you from doing that, or what you would gain in this respect by using a higher-order functor. You can still declare your monitoring functions in a module `Sampler`, then pass them to the loop function: `loop ~monitor:Sampler.my_function ...`. Compared to using a higher-order functor,  each such call replaces a single instantiation of the functor, and you still have a nice place to hide helper code.

Comment: yes, i agree, i can bundle the monitor functions and call them explicitly as optional arguments at each relevant call site. in my actual code, i have different points along the loop where i would want to sample; the monitor function here is just one of these points. so i typically have one 'run configuration' with one value for each of the monitoring functions. so ideally, the sampling functor would only need to be instantiated once, specifying the whole configuration. then there would no need to modify each call site explicitly.

Comment: Ok, thanks – that's useful information. See if my updated answer is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the updated thorough answer! the thing i was not getting is that if you parametrize a functor by a functor', you have to actually apply functor' inside the body of functor in order to get at all the good stuff. kind of obvious once you know it... i'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

Building on the functor part of [antron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528696/3240588), this is what I am currently using. It is still a bit involved, and maybe it could be made more concise, but it has some nice advantages. Namely: the monitoring of individual aspects can be switched on and off in a centralized place (a module of type `SAMPLER`) and arbitrary types can be exported, even if they become defined only somewhere inside the simulator module.

I define the monitoring (=sampling) modules and module types like so:

```
module type STYPE = sig type t end

module type SSAMPLER = sig
  type t
  val ev : t React.event
  val mon : t -> unit
end

module type SAMPLER_FN = functor (Data : STYPE) -> SSAMPLER
  with type t := Data.t

(* stub sampler function for a single one *)
module Never : SAMPLER_FN = functor (Data : STYPE) -> struct
  let ev = React.E.never
  let mon = ignore
end

(* event primitive generating sampling function *)
module Event : SAMPLER_FN = functor (Data : STYPE) -> struct
  let (ev : Data.t React.event), mon' = React.E.create ()
  let mon = mon' ?step:None
end
```

Here, I am using the React library to generate output streams of data. The `React.E.never` event does nothing and corresponds to sampling being switched off. Then the full sampling configuration is specified like so:

```
(* the full sampling config *)
module type SAMPLER = sig
  val sampler_pos : (module SAMPLER_FN)
  val sampler_step : (module SAMPLER_FN)
  (* and several more... *)
end

module NoSampling : SAMPLER = struct
  let sampler_pos = (module Never: SAMPLER_FN)
  let sampler_step = (module Never: SAMPLER_FN)
  (* ... *)
end

(* default sampling config *)
module DefaultSampling : SAMPLER = struct
  include NoSampling
  (* this is only possible when using first class modules *)
  let sampler_pos = (module Event : SAMPLER_FN)
end
```

One could avoid the first-class modules, but then the convenient inclusion and override in `DefaultSampling` would not be allowed.

In the simulation library code this is used like this:

```
module type VEC = sig
  type t
  val zeropos : t
  val wiggle : t -> t
end

module Sim (V:VEC) (Sampler:SAMPLER) = struct
  module V = V                  

  module M = struct
    type t = { mutable pos : V.t }
    val create () = { pos=V.zeropos }
    module Sampler_pos = (val Sampler.sampler_pos) (struct type nonrec t = t end)
    let update f m = m.pos <- f m.pos
  end

  module Sampler_b = (val Sampler.sampler_b) (struct type t = int end)

  let loop n (running_data:M.t) = 
    for i = 1 to n do 
      (* monitor step number: *)
      Sampler_b.mon i;
      (* monitor current pos: *)
      Sampler_pos.mon running_data;
      M.update V.wiggle running_data
    done 

end
```

Here, the sampling functors are applied at appropriate places in the simulation loop. `(val ...)` is again necessary only because of the first class module wrapping.

Finally, in an application script, one would then do this:

```
module Simulator = Sim (V) (DefaultSampling);;

let trace = Simulator.M.Sampler_pos.ev
          |> React.E.fold (fun l h -> h :: l) []
          |> React.S.hold [];;

let init_m = Simulator.M.create () in
Simulator.loop 100 init_m;;

React.S.value trace;;
```

The last line then contains the accumulated list of values of type `Simulator.M.t` that occurred during the loop. Monitoring of the step counter (a silly example) is switched off. By making another sampling functor of type `SAMPLER` and parametrizing `Sim` by that, one could further customize the monitoring, if desired.

Comment: I'd love to hear how this functionality can be achieved completely without functors. One could let loop take a record or a module itself, but then this data would need to be passed around inside Sim, which seems suboptimal as well.